# How to use arrays in javascript to match up divs when event fires?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function

I have a set of two divs - First set: when people mouse over these divs, it will fire an event, Second set: when the event is fired, these divs will be displayed. 
When you mouse over a div in the first set, it should display its corresponding div in the second set. I thought an easy way to match the mouseover divs with the correct div to display would be using arrays. I've been able attach the event listeners properly, but I can't figure out how to set it up so that when you mouseover one object of an array, it displays the array object with the same index number. I think if I could figure out how to recoginze the index number of the object I am mousing over, I could get it to work. I've tried a lot of things, but haven't been able to create anything that works. Here's the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


//create array of divs to mouse over 
var ar = new Array();
ar[0] = $("#home"); 
ar[1] = $("#doc");

var length = ar.length;

//create array of divs to display when event is fired 
var des = new Array();
des[0] = $("#homeDes");
des[1] = $("#docDes");


// start for
for ( var i = 0; i< length; ++i )
{
ar[i].bind("mouseover",function(){$(des[i]).css("display","block");});
ar[i].bind("mouseout",function(){$(des[i]).css("display","none");});
} 
//end for

}); 
//end 

</script>
```

Comment: Instead of doing these you could put a data attribute to your source element to specify the target element selector and instead of looping through, specify a class to your sources and bind event to them. How does your html look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){


   //create array of divs to mouse over 
   var ar = new Array();
   ar[0] = $("#home"); 
   ar[1] = $("#doc");

   var length = ar.length;

   //create array of divs to display when event is fired 
   var des = new Array();
   des[0] = $("#homeDes");
   des[1] = $("#docDes");


   // start for
   for ( var i = 0; i< length; ++i )
   {
       // WRAP THE BODY OF THE FOR LOOP IN A FUNCTION
       function(index) {
           ar[index].bind("mouseover",function() {
               $(des[index]).css("display","block");}
           );
           ar[index].bind("mouseout",function() {
               $(des[index]).css("display","none");
           });
       }(i);
   } 
   //end for

});
```

When the events are fired the value of `i` is the length of the array, you have to pass the value of `i` to another function so that in each function scope the value of `index` will be the value of `i` when it was called.

Comment: sure, that was a classical binding issue, 'i' being changed during the loop, one has to ensure each function in the the loop is bound not to 'i', but to 'i''s value at the time of binding. Another way would be to use Function.bind.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend toward making a more flexible approach to this so that you don't need to change your javascript when you change your HTML.  Consider classing your elements that need to have the bindings and providing data attribute to specify the target.  Your HTML for divs to be bound might look like this:

```
<div id="home" class="mouseoverToggleTrigger" data-target="#homeDes">...</div>
```

And the jQuery might look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.mouseoverToggleTrigger').hover(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).data('target'));
        $target.toggle();
    }
});
```

Note this is assuming you are using HTML5 for which jQuery, by default, converts `data-*` into values retrievable via `data()`.

For pages that are not HTML5, this more generalized solution will work

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.mouseoverToggleTrigger').hover(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).prop('data-target'));
        $target.toggle();
    }
});
```

One additional bit of flexibility this gives, is that you now don't have to limit yourself to a one-to-one trigger to target mapping.  You could specify a class name or other jQuery selector for `data-target` values to get highly customized behavior, such as one trigger toggling all elements of a certain class that are children of another class.

Comment: html5 not critical...can use `data-` in IE6 & 7 with jQuery.data()

Comment: @charlietfl Interesting. Thanks for noting. jQuery documentation only notes support for data attributes with regards to HTML5. Not sure how reliable this behavior may be across different browsers when not using HTML5.

Comment: they call them `html5 attributes` but concept has been usd for as long as jQuery has been around, but just using any arbitrary attribute, doesn't pass W3C validation but works nonetheless. Then when `data()` was introduced it matched up to `data-`

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach code wise is to give the common elements common classes and then use jQuery `index()` and `eq()` to match pairings

HTML

```
<a id="home" class="hoverMe">
<a id="doc" class="hoverMe">

<div id="homeDes" class="content">
<div id="docDes" class="content">
```

JS

```
var $content=$('.content')
var $links=$('.hoverMe').hover(function(){
    $content.eq( $links.index(this) ).show()

},function(){
     $content.eq( $links.index(this) ).hide()
})
```

[**index() API Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

[**eq() API Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: This assumes the trigger and target divs appear on the page in the same relative order.  As such, this is a very fragile approach.

Comment: @MikeBrant odds are typically well in favor of them being rendered in same order. OP will quickly find out if this approach won't work....howveer will also learn something from it

Comment: @charliefti Maybe. Maybe not.  We don't know from OP what the HTML source looks like.  Just figured it was important to note that this solution relies heavily on order in which elements are rendered on DOM.